# Django + PostgreSQL: query returning incorrect results

Tags: django, postgresql

In my application, I have created a view on the PostgreSQL database and mapped that view to a non-managed model in Django.

For some reason, when I query this model in Django, one of the tuples returns with an incorrect result.

This is my CREATE VIEW code:

```
  CREATE VIEW test_view_a AS
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY account_id, person_id)::int AS id,
  AVG(EXTRACT(epoch FROM date_trunc('second', meeting_time)))::int AS avg_meeting_time,
  AVG(EXTRACT(epoch FROM date_trunc('second', office_time)))::int AS avg_office_time,
  AVG(EXTRACT(epoch FROM date_trunc('second', traffic_time)))::int AS avg_traffic_time,
  account_id,
  person_id
  FROM test_view_b
  GROUP BY account_id, person_id
  ORDER BY account_id, person_id;
```

This is the data returned when I query directly in the database:

```
 id | avg_meeting_time | avg_office_time | avg_traffic_time | account_id | person_id 
----+------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+-----------
  1 |            64800 |               0 |             1514 |          1 |         8
  2 |            14400 |               0 |            29290 |          3 |         9
  3 |            14400 |               0 |                0 |          3 |        10
(3 rows)
```

When I query this view through Django, the second and third lines are returned correctly, but the first line is returned with avg_meeting_time as -1144800 and avg_traffic_time as 1202400:

```
>>> from test.models import *
>>> queryset = ViewA.objects.all()
>>> '%i %i' % (queryset[0].avg_meeting_time, queryset[0].avg_traffic_time)
'-1144800 1202400'
```

I have tried querying this view directly through the django.db.connection object, and even have tried executing the query that generates the view this way. The result is always the same, different from what is on the database.

I am using a spatial database with PostGIS, if that matters. I have tried switching the backend to psycopg2, but got the same result.

What's going on?

Comment: Can you post the model that is being used?

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug you

```
>>> from test.models import *
>>> queryset = ViewA.objects.all()
>>> '%i %i' % (queryset[0].avg_meeting_time, queryset[0].avg_traffic_time)
```

with

```
from django.db import connection
connection.queries
```

And agree with Burhan Khalid - model will be usefull

Answer (score 0):

You should check yours settings.py Do You have correct locale?

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'